# The first family

Tags: meaning

Does the First family means the family of the U.S President here? Are there any other meanings of it?

The few locations that exist on the South Side are in higher income neighborhoods like Hyde Park, the stomping grounds of University of Chicago students and the First Family.
http://www.eater.com/a/starbucks-income-map

Comment: What did you find when you [looked this up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/first-family?q=first+family)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression "[First Family](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/first+family)" has the following two connotations, in your extract it refers to the second one:

> - a family having the highest or one of the highest social ranks in a given place.
> - (often caps.) the family of the president of the U.S. or the family of the governor of a state.

(Collins Dictionary)

The expression "[First Family](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/first-family)" is an Americanism that dates back to the first half of the 19th century.

[First Family](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Family_of_the_United_States):

> - In the United States, the term "First Family" in casual reference to the President's immediate family, is most often used by the media and in particular, the White House press corps. Individually, each member of the First Family is designated a Secret Service codename by the United States Secret Service. Used by special agents, these code names uniquely identify members of the First Family for their ongoing protection as well as for the sake of brevity, clarity, and tradition.

Wikipedia